# How to convert reconstructed mesh into depth map?

Tags: python, c++, 3d, depth

I have reconstructed mesh stored in **.ply** format. In addition I have color images of some scenes and camera intrinsic and extrinsic for each image. How can I produce corresponding depth map given camera intrinsic and extrinsic parameters and reconstructed mesh? Are there any algorithms or libraries which can solve this problem?